# Impex Export: Colon in multivalue attribute is escaped by double backslash - How to remove this behavior?

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

Hybris: 6.3.0.0-SNAPSHOT (the behavior is the same with 6.3.0.21)

When exporting impex, we noticed a difference when exporting a non-multivalue Type attribute versus exporting a multivalue Type attribute.

When exporting String attribute data without colon, a non-multivalue attribute can be exported as **Experts**, while a multivalue attribute can be exported as **Experts|Hybris**.

When exporting Type with String attribute data with colons (e.g. URL), the colon is escaped with a double backslash (for multivalue only). A non-multivalue attribute can be exported as **https://experts.hybris.com**, while a multivale attribute can be exported as **https\://experts.hybris.com** if there is only 1 value or as **https\://experts.hybris.com|https\://help.hybris.com** if there are 2 values.

How can I stop the export from escaping the colon? Is there a method I can override to change this behavior? I would like to change the result to **https://experts.hybris.com|https://help.hybris.com** or to **"https://experts.hybris.com"|"https://help.hybris.com"**.

**Business Case:** We want to copy the URL from the exported impex, but the URL contains double backslashes. The exported impex is not meant to be reimported.

**Notes #`:** The URLs are stored in a collection (e.g. Product.newAttribute, where newAttribute is a collection of custom types which has a String). So, the Impex header looks something like "INSERT_UPDATE Product;newAttribute(data)"

**Notes #2:** (UPDATE: Didn't work) Currently, I'm checking if it's possible with a CSVCellDecorator; this is for import only.

**Notes #3:** Currently, I'm checking if it's possible with AbstractSpecialValueTranslator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this specific case, I created a new translator, extending AbstractValueTranslator. Then, I implemented the exportValue method, joining the string data (which are URLs), without escaping them.

```
public String exportValue(final Object value) throws JaloInvalidParameterException
{
    String joinedString = "";
    if (value instanceof Collection)
    {
        final Collection valueCollection = (Collection) value;
        if (!valueCollection.isEmpty())
        {
            final ArrayList<CustomType> list = (ArrayList<CustomType>) valueCollection;
            final StringJoiner joiner = new StringJoiner("|");
            for (final CustomType customType : list)
            {
                // data is a URL
                joiner.add(customType.getData());
            }
            // value would be something like "https://experts.hybris.com|https://help.hybris.com"
            joinedString = joiner.toString();
        }
    }

    return joinedString;
}
```

**Reference:**

- Customization: https://help.hybris.com/1808/hcd/ef51040168d743879c015b7de232ce40.html

Answer (score 0):

I think that might not be possible, since the colon is used to separate keys for referenced types. As in

```
...;catalogVersion(catalog(id),version);...
...;myCatalog:Staged;...
```

Why not run search/replace on the result?

Comment: Thanks, Johannes! I'm aware of this behavior, and search/replace may not be ideal in this case since the User is not very technical. However, the exported data is not meant to be reimported. It's just for the User to copy and paste somewhere (in this case, copy the URL). Also, there is only one attribute being exported (myCatalog without Staged, for example. So, there are no keys to separate). If there is no way to change the behavior, we are planning to redesign our data model.

Comment: Just wanted to share my thoughts. Looking forward for your fix. Good luck!

Comment: Just went with a translator, and posted it as answer. It's good enough for my strange case. :)